# Is there a way to deserialize part of an object in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

Hypothetical scenario: output stream of objects of type `Message` that implement `Serializable`. `Message` has members `Header` and `Body`. `Header` is small and `Body` can be large. Say I want to write a filter based on info in the `Header`: is there a way to do it without having to deserialize `Body`?

Comment: Serialize them separately, store two objects and read only the first one?

Comment: Let's say breaking up `Message` is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom readObject() to read only the fields you want.
If you only want to read the Header, you need to take care that you serialize the Header first and then the body. Then in your custom readObject() method you can choose to read only the first element.

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

  private transient String header;
  private transient String body;

  ...
  // custom write object that writes header first and then body
  private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos)
      throws IOException {
    oos.defaultWriteObject();
    // explicitly store the transient fields
    oos.writeObject(header);
    oos.writeObject(body);
  }

  private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream ois) 
      throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ois.defaultReadObject();
    // explicitly read in the transient fields
    header = (String) ois.readObject();
    if (needBody()) { // use some static/thread local variable to set this condition
      body = (String) ois.readObject();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is looking promising. How can I set `needBody()` switch based on the header? I can imagine right after `header = (String) ois.readObject();` I could say `setNeedBody(StaticFilter.isGoodHeader(header))`, but what if I have different consumer-specific filters? Edit: I guess I could call static method to get ThreadLocal filter. Let me try this. Again, thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @user443854 a ThreadLocal variable lookup with true/false should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

You shall NOT serialize Body in the first place by declaring it [`transient`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#78119).

But if you already have serialized the Message object, there is no way to selectively deserialize specific members.

Comment: In this made-up example, message body is there for a reason. It carries info that is useful to consumer, provided header passed filter.

Comment: @user443854: In that case, refer my second point. You CANNOT selective deserialize.

Comment: @user443854: In its raw form no. You will have to define ObjectStreamField. Source : http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/ Look for under the title "Using ObjectStreamField"

Comment: I do not see how this helps. `private final static ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields = {...}` allows to specify which members get serialized and in which order. How does it help avoid deserializing `Body`?

Comment: @user443854 : Agreed, its possible only for class level variables. So the answer to your question is Still No.

Answer (score 2):

You just discovered one of the weaknesses of object-oriented programming compared to databases: "What if I just want half of a Customer object?"

What I would say is that you need to split your Message class into something like MessageHeader, with the header information and no reference to the body, and a MessageBody class that has the body and a key that can be used to look up the header data.  Then you need to store and retrieve the serialized MessageHeader and MessageBody objects separately.

Comment: "object-oriented programming compared to databases"?  that's not even as close as apples and oranges.

Comment: Well, it's not really a weakness of object-oriented programming... OO says that you should not put stuff into one object that does not belong together. Anyway, your solution is spot-on.